# React Material ui: want to display all searched li items on top of all other fields

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, list, material-ui

Want to display all the searched li items on the top all field.
[image: want something like green border not like on the customer search]

In the above image in Customer email search input field, it will do api call with search key and display the result in li elements. So I want  all the li elements top of all fields with scroll. Like device type with scroll(green border).

Comment: You should probably give the Autocomplete component a better look. It has the features that you're after, already built-in. https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#search-as-you-type

Comment: Thanks for you quick response @2DH, but initially the my users array is empty. Once the user click on the search button then Only we are getting the users data. But as per my understanding *Autocomplete* options props works with filled array only